# Is it possible to set custom properties in an app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, app-config

I know how to interact with properties built into the .NET runtime using an app.config file, however, I would like to be able to set custom properties using the app.config file and cannot find information on how to do this by manually editing the file by hand (I do not wish to use the designer to create a settings file as we already have one that I don't want the designer to touch). As an example for what my ultimate goal is, I'd like to be able to do something like the following for a service (this is just pseudo-xml, if the syntax is correct, it's totally by coincidence):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <my.assembly.namespace>
      <application>
         <UsageStatistics logging="on" path="relative/or/absolute/path.log" otherproperties... />
      </application>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Where UsageStatistics is a static class I've created which will be used to toggle various logging options, including a property to set logging to on, and other various properties to control what is logged, where, and how often, etc.

Rather than just a straight answer, it would be great if a link to any relevant articles explaining how the app.config file works could be included or posted so I can try to figure out the answer on my own, rather than having it spoon-fed to me. I Googled for a bit trying to figure out how to implement this on my own, but could not find any clear-cut articles explaining how to set user-defined properties outside of the designer.

I would also like to point out that I do not wish to use environment variables to configure features within this service (there would be too many properties for the end user to create and maintain).

Many thanks in advance for help on this!

Comment: Have a look at creating custom config sections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Does this pertain to ASP.NET services/applications only? My service does not use ASP.NET

Comment: As @Brandon said, you need Custom Configuration Sections. But look at this fine [series of articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

Comment: Awesome, both of these are exactly what I'm looking for. Gotta love CodeProject, and I never would have thought to check the ASP.NET area of MSDN. If either of you post your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brandon had a link which was exactly what I needed to implement my class, and @Steve had a link to a great Code Project article which explains System.Configuration very well. If you are having an issue with custom properties or you're having trouble understanding how app.config files work, I recommend giving both links a good readover.

[(MSDN) How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[(Code Project) Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)